# OpenPop.NET save to database or save file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, email, openpop

I'm using OpenPop.NET to retrieve emails from client. My idea is to have a service that's working on the background to keep storing new recieved mail from time to time instead of geting it from the client when the user tries to check it, because: performance.

So my question here is: is it a better idea to store the emails info to the database or save it to file as in the [OpenPop example](http://hpop.sourceforge.net/exampleSaveLoadMessage.php)

I was thinking the better would be a database solution, because `Message-ID` is [not unique](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/241425/Reading-emails-using-OpenPop-library-Problem-with) this way i could open email details using my own `IDMessage`. But this is my first time working with recieving emails and am not sure if there's any motive that i shouldn't do it this way. So i'm open to opinions and advices.

Comment: DB is more reliable and safe than ordinal files

Comment: of course that's my line of thought to. but as their example was saving to files i guessed there might be a reason for it.

Comment: I guess this is for simplicity. Anyway, there is no difference where mail goes (for your business logic) if you have DAL. Just make MyMail.SaveTo(...) and forget about it